# How we can add favorite item feature in Recycler View?

Tags: android

I was trying to add bookmark feature in Recycler view but I do not know how to implement this in Android.

Comment: you can do by it's position. you can find that favorite item position and change it's UI or whatever you want. Or please give some more information

Comment: show your code to get help

Answer (score 0):

To add bookmark feature in recycle view . you need to add a bookmark button icon in every list item. when you will click on bookmark icon . You need to get data off that item position.

Create another arraylist and add all bookmarked data into it.
Show all bookmarked data in bookmark data section in another recycle view list.

Hope this helps !